# Delphi XE7 - Placing a DateEdit component on a FlowLayout causes access violation error in FireMonkey MultiDevice App

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a Multi-Device Tabbed Application that I'm working on in Delphi XE7. I have a TVertScrollBox that contains a TFlowLayout. When I add labels and other controls I have no problems. For the moment I'm running as a 32-bit Windows App (same error with different address occurs when running as 64-bit Windows). When I drop a TDateEdit onto the flow layout I get:

[image]

If I drop a DateEdit anywhere else on the form it's ok.

I'm wondering if I have gone about the layout wrong by placing the flow layout inside the vertscrollbox or if it is just an XE7 bug.

Thanks in advance.

-edit

After some more investigation I can see that the error is thrown in FMX.StdCtrls function TCheckBox.GetIsChecked. This function has one statement:

```
Result := FIsChecked;
```

From this point I'm thinking I may need to subclass the DateEdit to make a workaround.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

- edit

Further investigation - if I cut the entire TVertScrollBox (and sub-components) and place on another tab, I get no issues...

Is there any issue with multiple TFlowLayouts on the same form?

Comment: Set TDateEdit.IsChecked to False. I don't think it should have that property but it does. The bug has been reported.

Comment: Thanks you. I had to set all other TDateEdit.IsChecked to false as well. For some reason the program only broke when adding the last TDateEdit.

Comment: I have my TDateEdit in a TListBoxItem so I don't think TFlowLayout is the cause.

Comment: @FMXExpress I'm also having this problem. Do you know if it has been solved?